# How to improve remote backup

Tags: windows-10, lan, samba, shared-folders, robocopy

I need to backup a large file (>20GB) onto a shared folder through a wired LAN.

I have used ROBOCOPY with no buffer (/J) and multithreaded (/MT:64).

Nevertheless task manager measures no more than 11Mbps in upload.

How can I accelerate such task?

Comment: Try [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/), but it won't help if the WiFi is not fast enough.

Comment: are you using `/b` backup mode option?

Comment: No, I honestly didn't fully understood what that option really does by reading the MS documentation

Comment: No need of `/b` option. Instead, I will try `/compress` since I am transferring through SMB